# $\mathbb{C}$ is not isomorphic to any subring of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is there a proof that $\mathbb{C}$ is not isomorphic to any subring of $\mathbb{R}$? I have seen the proof that $\mathbb{C}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, is there any way to generalize this to arbitrary subrings?

Comment: Doesn’t the same proof work?

Comment: No, but the standard proof works just as well: $-1$ still can’t be a square inside the reals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $f\colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a ring homomorphism. Let $r = f(i)\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $r^2 = f(i)^2 = f(i^2) = f(-1) = -f(1) = -1$. But $-1$ is not a square in $\mathbb{R}$, contradiction.

Comment: This proves the result because in order for $\mathbb{C}$ to be isomorphic to a subring of $\mathbb{R}$, there must exist an injective homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, where the image is the subring, correct?

Comment: Yes, an isomorphism $h\colon \mathbb{C}\to R$, where $R\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a subring, is also a homomorphism $h\colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{R}$. @Tasso